# Replacing text in a single Beamer frame

Tags: beamer, overlays

I would like to be able to write on a single frame several sentences consecutively, in a precise order. Suppose that each line break corresponds to a different slide. Is there a way to get the following ?

> Sentence 1
>
> Sentence 1 and sentence 2
>
> Sentence 1 and sentence 3
>
> Sentence 1, sentence 3 and sentence 4
>
> Sentence 1, sentence 3 and sentence 5
>
> Sentence 1 and sentence 6

Also, my goal would be for the text of a given sentence to be at the same place on every slide. Moreover, I would like not to have a "hole" in my slide when sentence 2 dissapears (i.e. when sentence 3 appears, it should take the place of sentence 2).

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: So far your question is unclear. What you try so far? Do you read `beamer` documentation (The Beamer class, User Guide)? In *Part V Howtos* are described all possibilities how *How To Uncover Things Piecewise*. Please test there given example and see, which one is the best fit what you like to have.

Answer (score 3):

It's not completely clear which is the behavior you want when a disappearing sentence is larger (vertically) than an appearing one, but you can get started with this:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{New frame title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item <1-> Sentence 1 \uncover<2->{and \alt<3->{sentence 3.}{sentence 2 which is very large and will make another line but then it will absorbed back.}}
        \item <4-> Sentence 1, sentence 3 \uncover<5->{and \alt<6->{sentence 5.}{sentence 4}}
        \item <7-> Sentence 1 and sentence 6.
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]